# Where Truecaller chat is stored on phone memory?

Tags: database

Where are Chat messages stored ? Is it in some database on phone or some file?
Please help me with path to db or file.

Answer (score 0):

this is the path

```
/data/data/com.truecaller/databases/freshchat.db
```